# Task of type Javadoc as a separate groovy class

Tags: gradle

I have a task of type Javadoc like this:

```
class CreateJavadocsTask extends Javadoc{
@TaskAction
def action1()
 {
    project.source = project.android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    options.linkSource true
    classpath += project.files(project.android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    failOnError false
 }

 }
```

This task gives an error that task is up to date as it has no source files:

Baloe is the stacktrace :

Using incremental javac compilation. Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature. Not using incremental javac compilation. Using incremental javac compilation. Not using incremental javac compilation. Using incremental javac compilation. All projects evaluated. [buildinfo] Not using buildInfo properties file for this build. Selected primary task 'createJavadocs12' from project : Tasks to be executed: [task ':bluetooth:createJavadocs12'] :bluetooth:createJavadocs12 (Thread[main,5,main]) started. :bluetooth:createJavadocs12 Skipping task ':bluetooth:createJavadocs12' as it has no source files. :bluetooth:createJavadocs12 UP-TO-DATE :bluetooth:createJavadocs12 (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.034 secs.

Comment: What you have put as action actually looks like configuration. Why do you need to subclass `Javadoc` at all?

Comment: That's required.I need to write all my tasks as independent classes. Any idea how to write this as a separate class, works in the plugin class but I want to make it work as a separate class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a lot of struggle this worked for me

```
class CreateJavadocsTask extends Javadoc{
@TaskAction
def action1()
{
project.source = project.android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
options.linkSource true
classpath += project.files(project.android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
failOnError false
}
}
```